# HTML5 audio won't play sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

In my application, I am creating 10 audio object and I store them in a browser variable. Based on the scenario, I will pick one of them and will assign it to one global variable. Then I play that sound. After some time I will stop and clear that audio from the global variable.

I am verifying the readystate whenever I play the sound. I capture Play & Pause events.

The problem is that sometimes the sound is not audible but play & pause events are still fired. I am not able to reproduce it all the times (it happens randomly).

Please let me know if anyone faced this kind of issue.

```js
function Sound(){}
try
{
 if(new Audio().canPlayType("audio/wav") != "" && new Audio().canPlayType("audio/wav") != "no" ){
  Sound.extn="wav";//No I18N
 }
 else{
  Sound.extn="mp3";//No I18N
 }
}
catch (e) {
}

Sound.init=function(soundsobj)
{
 for (var tunename in soundsobj) 
 {
  var audioobj = new Audio(soundsobj[tunename]);
  audioobj.setAttribute("autobuffer", "true");
  audioobj.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    Sound.cache[tunename]=this;
    });

  audioobj.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    this.currentTime = 0;
    });
  Sound._SOUND_PLAYER.addEventListener( "play", function(){console.log(this.readyState);}, false);
  Sound._SOUND_PLAYER.addEventListener( "pause", function(){console.log(this.readyState);}, false);

 }
}

Sound.playTune=function(tunename,duration)
{

 if(Sound.cache[tunename])
 {

  var cachedsound = Sound.cache[tunename];
  if(cachedsound.readyState == 4)
  {
   cachedsound.currentTime = 0;
   Sound._SOUND_PLAYER = cachedsound;
   Sound.play(duration);
  }
  else
  {
   delete Sound.cache[tunename];
   var audioobj = new Audio(soundsobj[tunename]);
   audioobj.setAttribute("autobuffer", "true");
   audioobj.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
     Sound.cache[tunename]=this;
     Sound._SOUND_PLAYER = this;
     Sound.play(duration);
   });

  }
 }
}

Sound.play = function(duration)
{
 Sound._SOUND_PLAYER.loop=true;
 Sound._SOUND_PLAYER.play();
 clearTimeout(Sound.cleartimer);
 Sound.cleartimer = setTimeout(function(){Sound.stop()},duration*1000);
}

Sound.stop=function()
{
 try
 {
  if(Sound._SOUND_PLAYER)
  {
   Sound._SOUND_PLAYER.pause();
  }
  Sound._SOUND_PLAYER = undefined;
 }
 catch(e){}
}
```

Comment: Does this happen only on Google Chrome?

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: Yes. As of now i am facing this issue in chrome. Shared my code.

Comment: you had your code in the html part of the snippet. i moved it to the js part

Comment: use a double equals sign when comparing values. Also it helps to spell correctly- your function has an extra c in it on two occasions.

Comment: @RachelGallen Yes. It is typo error.It happens when i paste the code here.

Comment: Any suggestion guys?

Comment: @Alexis Any suggestion in my code?